# Como entender el siguiente parse?

Tags: flutter

```
Estoy siguiendo un tutorial de GitHub y me quedo bloqueado al intentar entender el sentido de este *parse*: `return int.parse(packageInfo.buildNumber) < snapshot.value;
```

Efectivamente llevais razón y os pongo casi todo el código del modulo. faltaría el final del mismo, pero si lo necesitáis, lo adjunto tambien.
Igualmente, he modificado el dato child(firebaseVersions) en la consola de Firebase y al probar en Android Studio veo que después de 2 horas, conserva el dato antiguo
Muchas gracias

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkCurrentUser();
    Offline.setKeepSynced(1, true);

    _filter = new Map<String, String>();
    _filter.addAll(widget.filter);
    _filter.remove(filterColor);
    _key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    _rateStateF = Prefs.getStringF(keyRateState, rateStateInitial);
    _isNewVersionF = PackageInfo.fromPlatform().then((PackageInfo packageInfo) {
      return FirebaseDatabase.instance
          .reference()
          .child(firebaseVersions)
          .child(Platform.isAndroid ? firebaseAttributeAndroid : firebaseAttributeIOS)
          .once()
          .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        return int.parse(packageInfo.buildNumber) < snapshot.value;
      });
    });
```

Comment: Podrías elaborar un poco mejor la pregunta? Un poco más específica para que se pueda entender mejor?

Comment: Podrías también incluir el tutorial y decir en que línea, para que entremos en contexto todos.

Answer (score 0):

No se si los tiros van por ahí, pero si el valor devuelto de `packageInfo.buildNumber` es distinto de entero, tipo string o algun otro tipo de dato numérico no entero, lo que se pretende es poder hacer una comparación entre dos enteros tratando de convertir ese valor no entero a ello. Por lo tanto como valor devuelto obtendrás el resultado de esa comparación de una forma correcta dado que si probablemente su valor es string, comparar string con entero no sería algo apropiado. 
Si no es así y estoy equivocado por favor házmelo saber para comprenderlo mejor. Saludos.